# EF Database Engines Specifics

Tags: database, entity-framework

Does Entity Framework work only on the common denominator of all the database engines it supports? or does it also allow its users to use features that are specific to each engine when needed?

Comment: This question is unclear and too broad. _Which_ specific features are you looking for? There's always a way to execute raw SQL, if that's what you're looking for. There's also the `DbFunctions` class, which contains common (there that word is again) functions that the relevant provider (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...) translates to database-specific syntax.

Comment: I didn't mean any specific feature, I just wanted to know if I might face the condition when I need to use a feature that is only exclusive to Oracle for example, just wanted to know if this might cause me a problem down the road if I decide to us EF.